# Revolution Slider template - Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, slider, revolution-slider

[image]

Is it possible to set a template like this in Revolution Slider Wordpress plugin???
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using Revolution Slider for years but all I can say is that it's not meant for this sort of displays/carousels - at least not without lots and lots of coding.

This slider is more suitable for the template you need: http://codecanyon.net/item/showbiz-pro-responsive-teaser-wordpress-plugin/4720988